# tcpdf did not work

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, tcpdf

I have a question about TCPDF library in codeigniter. I got an error:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /home/mrakodol/public_html/ecarrent/ecarrent/tcpdf/cache/img_QwbOB4
```

I have 777 permission on that folder and have a .htaccess file like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Hide the application and system directories by redirecting the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCPDF seems to be extremely picky about filenames.  It's saying the cached file doesn't exist.  That probably means the cached file couldn't be generated, so check if any of your source images have punctuation, spaces, or other tricky characters in their filename.  Also make sure they are RGB format not CMYK, and make sure you have enough memory to process them.

Comment: Thanks. I figure it out. I remove image with name logo.jpg and it generate a pdf document correctly, but I want a image into pdf(logo of company). I convert image into RGB but it still do not work.

Comment: I find out. My address for image file is wrong. Thank you Cris.